# Can't connect to MongoDB Atlas from CentOS using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, centos, mongodb-atlas

I've created a cluster on MongoDB Atlas and have successfully connected to it using Compass and also using Node running locally. 
When I try to run the same code on my CentOS machine i get an `ECONNREFUSED`error. Here is my Node code

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://myuser:mypass@tablematic-0-z4nuk.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  console.log("ERROR: " + err);

  client.close();
});
```

`myuser` and `mypass` are replaced by my actual username and password here.

I've opened up server's firewall for ports `27015`, `27016` and `27017`.
Atlas is set up to accept connections from any incoming IP.

I really can't think of what might be causing it...

Comment: have tried to ping `tablematic-0-z4nuk.gcp.mongodb.net` from your centos vs where it is working and see if you see any difference?

Comment: i would also recommend to use mongo shell and run `mongo yourconnectionstring` and see if that is working from centos or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. It ended up being the cPanel Firewall, even though I've opened the ports through `firewall-cmd`, my cPanel was still bypassing that configuration with its own firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but my connection strings are usually like 
 `mongodb://user:pass@host.app:27017/db_name`